# Iterating over days in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've tried the following:

```
def next_seven_days
  today = Date.today
  (today .. today + 7).each { |date| puts date } 
end
```

But this just gives me the first and last date. I can't figure out how to get all the ones in between.

I was trying to follow the example here: http://www.whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Dates_and_times

Comment: Using your exact code, I get the desired results.

Comment: Don't know what your problem is. I get this result:2011-07-07
2011-07-08
2011-07-09
2011-07-10
2011-07-11
2011-07-12
2011-07-13
2011-07-14

Comment: What are you using to run your code?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was weird. I'm calling the helper method in the view this way `<%= next_seven_days %>`

Comment: It's working in the IRB, but not the view.

Comment: Should've mentioned it's Rails 3.1rc4

Comment: You get the first and the last date because the last statement evaluates into an object of a `Range` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
def next_seven_days
  today = Date.today
  (today .. today + 7).inject { |init, date|  "#{init} #{date}" } 
end
```

In this case, the return value is a concatenated string containing all the dates.

Alternatively, if it's not a concatenated string you want, you could change the `"#{init} #{date}"` part of it.

As a side note, using `puts` in ruby on rails won't print to the web page. When you use `<%= next_seven_days %>`, the return value of that function is what will be printed to the page. The `each` function returns the range in parentheses.

Comment: I think `.to_a.join(" ")` would be more readable than using `inject` for this.

Comment: You're probably right. I have a feeling the OP doesn't really want a string list of dates, and is currently trying to make sure they're correctly iterating through the dates before moving on to the next step. If they really want a list of dates, `collect` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will definitely print all eight days to stdout. Your problem is that you're looking at the return value (which since `each` returns `self` will be `(today .. today + 7)`).

Note that if you print to stdout inside an erb template, that won't cause the output to show up in the rendered template.

Answer (score 2):

Your function RETURNS an enumeration designated by 2011-07-07..2011-07-14 which is displayed in your view, but your puts prints to STDOUT which is not going to be your view, but the console screen your server is running in =)

If you want your view to show a list of the seven days, you need to actually create the string that does that and RETURN that :)

```
def next_seven_days
  outputstr = ""
  today = Date.today
  (today..(today+7.days)).each { |date| outputstr += date.to_s }
  return outputstr 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def next_seven_days
  today = Date.today
  (today..(today+7.days)).each { |date| puts date } 
end
```

Comment: I'm just getting `2011-07-07..2011-07-14` with that in my view.

Comment: Note that the `.days` call is unneeded - it's valid to add an integer to a date, it just increases the days by that amount.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "next" method

```
        def next_seven_days
          today= Date.today
          7.times do 
             puts today
             today=today.next
           end
        end
```